# C# Executemultiplerequest For Two Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamics-crm

I'm creating web application for uploading/importing excel file into ms dynamics CRM. This web application work fine if there is only a single entity within the excel file. But the web application won't import if there are two entities within excel file.

Here is the code that I have:

```
protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
        st.Start();


        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string Filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string Folderpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];

            string Filepath = Server.MapPath(Folderpath + Filename);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Filepath);

            DataTable dt = ImportData(Filepath, Extension);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Entity contractline = new Entity("new_contractline");

                        contractline["new_contractid"]  = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        contractline["new_lineitem"] = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();

                        Entity productitem = new Entity("new_productitem");
                        productitem["new_instanceid"] = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                        productitem["new_productnumber"] = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();


                        var multiplerequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
                        {
                            Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                            {
                                ContinueOnError = false,
                                ReturnResponses = true
                            },
                            Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
                        };

                        CreateRequest createcontractline = new CreateRequest { Target = contractline };
                        CreateRequest createproductitem = new CreateRequest { Target = productitem };
                        multiplerequest.Requests.Add(createcontractline);
                        multiplerequest.Requests.Add(createproductitem); 

                        ExecuteMultipleResponse multirespon = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(multiplerequest);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Label1.Text = ex.Message;
                    }


                }
                st.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = st.Elapsed;

                Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count + "Records created, total time consume is " + ts;
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Tidak ada data yang dipilih";
            }
        }
    }
    private DataTable ImportData(string Filepath, string Extension)
    {
        string connString = "";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        switch (Extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        connString = string.Format(connString, Filepath, 1);

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            OleDbCommand excelCmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            excelCmd.Connection = excelConn;

            excelConn.Open();
            DataTable dtexcelschema;
            dtexcelschema = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string SheetName = dtexcelschema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            excelConn.Close();

            excelConn.Open();
            excelCmd.CommandText = "Select * from [" + SheetName + "]";
            oda.SelectCommand = excelCmd;
            oda.Fill(dt);
            excelConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

My question is how to use `createrequest` for two entities. As you can see above, i tried to call `createrequest` twice. But it won't work after all.

Comment: What do you mean with "it won't work after all"? Do you get an exception, at which point does your code fail?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen: Hii henk, i didn't get any exception. My code fail to import data into ms dynamic crm.  You can see i placed code: `Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count + "Records created, total time consume is " + ts;` there. Actually the code can read how many record within excel file. But it can't insert the data into ms crm.

Comment: Could it be the records are actually created, but not associated with their contract record? In the line `contractline["new_contractid"]  = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();` it seems you are trying to associate a contract line record with its contract. In that case `dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()` should return an `EntityReference` object; instead it returns a `string` value;

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen: The `["new_contractid"]` is the primary field of the contractline. There no need to use `EntityReference` at this point. 

No,the records are not created after all. If i just declare 1 `Entity`, also only use one create request. The records are created. Its seem the error come from the way i declare the second entity and the second create request.